# Autoplay youtube video when video appears in a certain container

Tags: jquery, youtube-javascript-api, magnific-popup

```
<div class="lightbox-trigger"></div>

<div class="lightbox-content autoplay"><iframe>...</iframe></div>

<div class="mfp-wrap"></div>
```

I have `.lightbox-trigger` that when clicked opens up `.lightbox-content` inside `.mfp-wrap`. By default, the `.lightbox-content` is hidden, and will only be visible once it is inside `.mfp-wrap`

When there is a YouTube video inside `.lightbox-content.autoplay`, I'd like for the video to autoplay once the video appears in `.mfp-wrap`.

I hope this makes sense. I tried this jQuery but it's not working for me...

```
$(".lightbox-trigger").click(function() { 
    $(".mfp-wrap .lightbox-content.autoplay iframe").attr("src").replace("?", "?autoplay=1&"); 
});
```

Comment: You're only getting attr `src` and replacing the string with autoplay. You need to assign it back to src.

Comment: `var iframe = $(".mfp-wrap .lightbox-content.autoplay iframe");  iframe[0].src  = attr("src").replace("?", "?autoplay=1&");` something like this might work

Comment: Thanks @sertsedat, I thought I was missing something. Unfortunately, it's still not working for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using the following:

```
// add parameter when opening video in popup
$(".lightbox-trigger").on("click", function() { 
    $(".mfp-wrap .et_pb_video.autoplay iframe").each(function(){
        var addautoplay = $(this).attr("src")+"&autoplay=1";
        $(this).attr("src",addautoplay);
    });
});

//for removing the parameter when closing the video
$('.lightbox-overlay').click(function() { 
    $(".et_pb_video.autoplay iframe").each(function(){
        var removeautoplay = $(this).attr("src").replace("&autoplay=1", "");
        $(this).attr("src",removeautoplay);
    });
    $.magnificPopup.close();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Youtube video embed link - Add property

```
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media";
```

Sample iFrame Link:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/iVe__Py2GuU" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Example:

```
$(".lightbox-trigger").click(function() { 
    $(".mfp-wrap .lightbox-content.autoplay iframe").attr("src").replace("?", "?allow=autoplay; encrypted-media&"); 
});
```

Comment: The allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" is there, but the jQuery isn't doing anything...